# Flutter adding Prefix to Json source

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get fetch data from Json and it works. The problem is I have to use at least 2 different json file and merge them.

the code works without any prefix

```
      "https://www.domain.bg/index.php?route=services/products/GetAllCategories"
```

but I have another json file getArticleDetail&article_id=103

I am formatting to endPointUrl to

```
final endPointUrl = "https://www.domain.bg/index.php?route=services/products/"
```

now I am trying to add prefix

```
Response res = await get(endPointUrl + "getAllCategories");
```

but this query does not work. As I remember this method works under android but not under Flutter.
Any help?

Comment: I think it should work! what is the error? have you used `http.get`?

Comment: I cannot list the categories when I use + json
There is no any error message

Comment: sorry but your question is not clear though...